# not(0) +1 почему равно False?

Tags: python

Никак не могу понять почему (not(0) +1) даёт False в результате на Python. Ведь not(0) это True.

Comment: Но если ввести print(True+ 1) в результате получится 2.

Comment: print(int(True)) выводит 1.

Comment: Задачу я уже решил, переводя в int, но так и не понял почему not(0) +1 равно False :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Потому, что вы неправильно читаете выражение.

```
not(0) + 1
not (0) + 1
not ((0) + 1)
not (0 + 1)
not 0 + 1
not 1
```

Эти все выражения эквивалентны. Ибо `not` - это не функция, а оператор. И операция "логический не" имеет более низкий приоритет чем сложение.

А вот выражение `(not 0) + 1` даст в результате искомое `2`.

Comment: Спасибо большое!